# How to make a custom Windows icon not blur?

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

I converted a png file into a fav.ico online for a Winform program. When the icon is displayed on my desktop, it looks blur. Is there any specific requirements to make the icon sharper?

Answer (score 0):

Error is fixed after I included a space before a capital letter in the filename.

> **FileName.exe** changed to **File Name.exe**